# The 4 outputs of a linear model in R

Tags: r, plot, regression, linearmodels

In R, after creating a linear model using the function `model <- lm()` and plotting it using `plot(model)`, you will get back 4 graphs each displaying your model differently. Can anyone explain what these graphs mean?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Robinson-icebreaker.pdf , section 9.3

Comment: [Note to moderators: this is one of those questions that might seems inappropriate but I think lots of people, in particular students, will benefit from a good answer located in one place.]

Comment: Yes please I am a student and new to R. A simplified explanation of those 4 models would help a lot

Answer (score 3):

`plot.lm` can produce 6 different diagnostic plots, controlled by the `which` parameter. These are:

1. a plot of residuals against fitted values
2. a Normal Q-Q plot
3. a Scale-Location plot of sqrt(| residuals |) against fitted values
4. a plot of Cook's distances versus row labels
5. a plot of residuals against leverages
6. a plot of Cook's distances against leverage/(1-leverage)

By default it will produce numbers 1, 2, 3 and 5, pausing between plots in interactive mode.

You can see them all in one go if you set up the graphics device for multiple plots, eg:

```
mdl <- lm(hp~disp,mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
plot(mdl,which=1:6)
```

[image: lm diagnostic plots]

Interpretation of these plots is a question for Cross Validated, though `?plot.lm` gives some basic information.